# Asterisk - Make a call inside a conference with ringtone

Tags: asterisk, sip, asteriskami, agi

I'm trying to make a call inside a running conference and hear the ringtone.

*Note: the conference is already running I have only the admin inside.

I already tried different approaches to make the call without success

**1) Originate:**

channel originate SIP/000000000@provider application ConfBridge ConferenceName

*This works, makes the call and when its answered it joins the conference, **but no ringtone***

**2) ConfBridge Menu, dialplan_exec**

```
[default_menu]

type=menu

1=dialplan_exec(addcaller,000000000,1)


[addcaller]
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX,1,Originate(SIP/${EXTEN}@provider,app,ConfBridge,ConferenceName)
```

*This works, makes the call I have ringtone, but when answer, **no audio inside conference***

**3) Options 2 + a macro to join call after answer**

```
same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@provider,,M(joinconf))

[macro-joinconf]
exten => s,1,NoOp()
same => n,ConfBridge(ConferenceName)
same => n,Hangup()
```

*This works, I can hear the ringtone and then I can see the user inside the conference but again, **no audio!***

**4) All versions with variants**

I have tryied all sort of variants using

```
same => n,Answer()
same => n,Progress()
same => n,Wait(1)
```

cause maybe was the channel not answered, but I'm stuck.

**the final goal is a simple**

conference with the power of calling and hanging other phones.

No matter if I need to use:

- AMI with multiple commands
- channelredirect
- chanspy
- meetme
- AGI

**whatever just need to make it work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do  originate into Local channel, in dialplan use Ringing(r param in dial command) or moh with ringing sound

Comment: DAMN! geniuos! I tryied your solution and it simply works! but, why? I did a originate to a local channel with application as ending point and inside the dial plan a did the dialing with R and now I have both the ringtone and the voice! can u explain me why?

Comment: Macro and menu make call to muted state. It have alot of limitations. In that macro you should only send events,calcualtte variables and if do originate - do with delay.